# When should I Use AWS API Gateway Proxy Integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am new to AWS and I am setting up a API Gateway which will call a Lambda function that will post that data to a Kinesis Stream. The API Gateway Post request will contain several request parameters.

I am reading through the AWS docs and I see 2 options for accessing the request parameters.

1) Via the $input Variable [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference)

2) via Proxy Integration [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-proxy-resource?icmpid=docs_apigateway_console)

Can you please explain the use case for proxy integration vs using the input variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, if you control the backend integration interface (as you would with a Lambda function) you should use the 'proxy' integration because it's much easier to manipulate the data in your Lambda function code than in the API Gateway transformation.

If you don't control the backend integration interface (like Kinesis directly, or a legacy HTTP endpoint for example) then you can use the mapping template to transform the data between the client and the backend integration.

Does that make sense? For your use case using Lambda, you should use the proxy. If you wanted to try to use Kinesis directly as the backend, you would have to use a mapping template to construct the correct request to Kinesis.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. When using a proxy to pass request parameters  to the Lambda function how do I access each parameter individually in the function? I am looking at an example where we get a single parameter like this event.pathParameters.proxy. But this will get all params together.

Comment: Or do I need to parse this result on the lambda side with additional logic?

Comment: if you use a 'greedy' path parameter like {proxy+} then you just get the whole path as the parameter value. You can parse it in the function.

Comment: Thank @Jack Kohn, it's pretty easy to split using the split("/") method